# PHP session variables not carrying over

Tags: php

I have a controller/controller.php file that starts a session and sets some session variables. I then 'include' a model/model.php file and call a function to load it.

When I try and use the session variables from the controller.php file in the model.php file, I am getting many: Undefined variable: _SESSION errors.

Here is an example of setting a session variable in the controller.php file:

```
$_SESSION['userName'] = 'some data'
```

In the model.php file I am trying to retrieve it by this code:

```
print($_SESSION['userName']);
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT

my controller.php file code:

```
<?PHP

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['Login'])) {

$_SESSION['pointsForQuestion'] = '1';
$_SESSION['userName'] = $_POST['txtUsername'];

if(!is_file($_SESSION['userName'].".txt"))
{
    writeUserDetails($_SESSION['userName'],"1","0");
    $_SESSION['currentLevel'] = "1";
    $_SESSION['score'] = "0";
} else {
    readUserDetails($_SESSION['userName']);
}

print('logged in');

include('../model/model.php');
print page_load();

}   

function writeUserDetails($username,$level,$score) {
    $fh = fopen($username.".txt", 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, $level.",".$score);
    fclose($fh);
}

function readUserDetails($username) {
    $userDetails = explode(',', file_get_contents($username.".txt"));
    $_SESSION['currentLevel'] = $userDetails[0];
    $_SESSION['score'] = $userDetails[1];
}


?>
```

Comment: Have you done `unset($_SESSION)` anywhere ?

Comment: So we can better help you please show us the controller/controller.php file that starts a session and sets the session variables? Thanks

Comment: EDITED - added the PHP code. Do I need a session start/resume sort of statement in the model.php file maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Start your session before defining the session variables on top ie `session_start();`

**Edited** 
You have not set anything for these session variable that's why it is giving that error

```
$_SESSION['userName'];
$_SESSION['currentLevel'];
$_SESSION['score'];
```

You can delete these session variables if u dont want to set anything...

Comment: I set them in the if (isset($_POST['Login'])) { statement, that gets called when a user first logs in.

Comment: your error is just because of not defining the session variables before this if (isset($_POST['Login'])) { statement ..

Comment: Are these two lines correct:  include('../model/model.php');
 print page_load();

Comment: if you dont have include('...') error like file not found and page_load function not found error then it is correct in including and calling that file and function

Comment: OK, reedited. Still does not work. I see nothing wrong. Please help.

Comment: try print_r($_POST['Login']) and see if is set or not and check for 

if(!is_file($_SESSION['userName'].".txt"))... i think it is going in else... part...

Comment: I know for a fact that those lines are being run as the ../model/model.php is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

`$_SESSION` is a superglobal available in all scopes.

So, you must have forgotten `session_start()`.